# Lualatex, print over all pages

Tags: luatex, callback

I'd like to define in Lualatex a way to add a text after each page. For example, add a code that display a big stamp in the middle of the page *on top of the text* (`adbegshi` does something similar, but it adds the text at the beginning of the page) that displays the current page number. For now, the following code add this only at the end of the last page.

NB : I do NOT want to use an external file and use `pdfpages` to include the pages, I'd like to have a solution in one single file.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}%
\lipsum[1-20]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[text=red] at (current page.center) {\Huge \textbf{\thepage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

-- EDIT --
The solution given solve indeed my problem, but I'm curious to know if it's possible to do that in "pure" lualatex, using hooks or something like that.
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

atbegshi offers the command `\AtBeginShipoutAddToBoxForeground` but normally I do find eso-pic easier to use for this sort of things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}%
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[text=red] at (current page.center) {\Huge \textbf{\thepage}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is `\AtPageCenter` macro with `eso-pic` which could be used here avoiding loading of tikz. (but I don't know exactly how tikz behaves when putting text at some location, for example here, is the 1 really centered in the page?)

Comment: Oh, I missed this great feature, thanks! And for educational purpose, does someone know if it's possible to do that in pure lualatex?

Comment: What do you mean by "pure" lualatex? The code works fine there.